# How can i find out what key is being pressed in a click event in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to see if a key or a modifier such as ALT,CTRL,etc is being pressed inside a Cell-Double-Click Event (or possibly any other events rather than key based events such as Key_Up or Key_Down etc).
How can i achieve this in C#?

Comment: *Cell Double_Click* is this C# VSTO excel? or Winform with a DataGridView or WPF, ASP.Net???

Comment: do you want to check which KEY or which MODIFIER (CTRL, ALT etc.)?
don't think, that's a good idea to make use of key+click events

Comment: I am working with a DataGridView in C#

Comment: @TheHe:I meant which modifier was pressed along with double clicking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the following if you reference `System.Windows.Input`

```
if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift)
```

Answer (score 1):

check this out: 
(sorry)

CHECK MSDN for `Keyboard.Modifiers` static property...

German:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.modifiers.aspx

English: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.modifiers.aspx